# How to set opacity to a background image in Ionic v6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I have an Ion Content, I need to put a background image there with 50% Opacity.

My welcome component html

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
     <ion-row>
      ...
```

My welcome component scss

```
ion-content
{
  --background: url(splash1.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
  --background-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The Background Image is shown, but there is no opacity. How I can fix it? I user Ionic v6 with Angular

Answer (score 0):

use css shadow part `background`:

```
ion-content
{
  --background: url(splash1.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
ion-content::part(background)
{
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```